# Recover a table of varchar2 from a pl/sql function in php

Tags: php, plsql

I made a function in pl/sql that return a table of varchar2, I tested it on sqldeveloper and I know it works. But now, I want to retrieve this table with a php project. First of all, I tried this

```
oci_bind_by_name($stid,":returnValue",$returnValue);
```

But I'm getting this :

```
 Warning: oci_execute() [function.oci-execute]: ORA-06550: line 2, column 41: PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type ORA-06550: line 2, column 25: PL/SQL: Statement ignored in C:\xampp\htdocs\BCN_REQUETEUR\index.php on line 15
```

Then I tried with this

```
 oci_bind_array_by_name($stid,":returnValue",$returnValue,250,250);
```

But I'm getting the same error.
So, how can we retrieve this table of varchar2 in php ?
Thanks

Edit : I finally succeed, instead of using a pl/sql function, I used a procedure with an 'out parameter' and then in the php side :

```
 $query = "BEGIN 
             ecrire_requete(30, :thesechar); 
           END;";
 $stid = oci_parse($conn, $query);
 $tabvars = oci_new_collection($conn,'MYTABLETYPE');
 oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':thesechar', $tabvars, -1, SQLT_NTY);
 oci_execute($stid, OCI_DEFAULT);
 for ($i = 0;$i < count($tabvars);$i++) 
 { 
     echo "<br>".$tabvars->getElem($i);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think You can use pl/sql Like this....I used same pl/sql script Like you but not Preprocedure

```
<?php
$dbServerName = 'localhost';
$dbName = 'CGG1';
$dbUserName = 'SYSTEM';
$dbPassword = 'admin';

$port = 1521;

$c2 = oci_connect($dbUserName, $dbPassword, "(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = $dbServerName)(PORT = $port)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=$dbName)))");

if($c2)
{
    $v = "DECLARE
    --var_num1 number; 
    --var_num2 number; 
    BEGIN 
        --var_num1 := 100; 
        --var_num2 := 200; 
        DECLARE 
        var_mult number; 
        BEGIN 
            -- AMATIA_TIPO_ADMIN;
            delete from AMATIA_TIPO_ADMIN;
            Insert into AMATIA_TIPO_ADMIN (ID_TIPO_ADMIN,NOMBRE) values (8,'Vista Contratista');
            Insert into AMATIA_TIPO_ADMIN (ID_TIPO_ADMIN,NOMBRE) values (5,'Vista Matriz legal');
            Insert into AMATIA_TIPO_ADMIN (ID_TIPO_ADMIN,NOMBRE) values (6,'Superadministrador');
            Insert into AMATIA_TIPO_ADMIN (ID_TIPO_ADMIN,NOMBRE) values (7,'Vista Gestor');

            select max(ID_TIPO_ADMIN) into var_mult from AMATIA_TIPO_ADMIN;

            execute immediate
            'DROP SEQUENCE SEQ_AMATIA_TIPO_ADMIN';
            var_mult := var_mult + 1 ;
            execute immediate
            'CREATE SEQUENCE SEQ_AMATIA_TIPO_ADMIN INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH '|| var_mult || ' MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 MINVALUE 0 CACHE 20';
        END; 
    END; 
    ";
    $stid = oci_parse($c2, $v);

    $checkExe = oci_execute($stid);

    echo $checkExe . "<hr>";
}
else
{
    echo "NOT SUCCESS";
}
?>
```