# ORA-06550, PLS-00103, ORA-06512 on function

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, ora-06550, ora-06512, pls-00103

I have no idea what to do. I wrote a function, compiled it with no errors but then when I run the code I got:

```
ORA-0650: line 3, column 14:

PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "/" when expecting one of the following:

:= . ( @ % ; not null range default character

ORA-06512: at line 58

Vendor code 6550
```

This is the function:

```
create or replace 
FUNCTION "GET_MUSICIAN_FUN" 
( 
i_mus_id IN musicians.id%type
)
RETURN musicians%ROWTYPE
AS
o_mus_rec musicians%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
  SELECT m.id, m.first_name, m.last_name, m.born, m.died , m.picture_path, m.bio
  INTO o_mus_rec
  FROM musicians m
  WHERE id = i_mus_id;
  RETURN o_mus_rec;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20005, 'Found nothing.');
  WHEN TOO_MANY_ROWS THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20006, 'Found too many.');
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20007, 'Cannot get musician.');
END GET_MUSICIAN_FUN;
```

EDIT:

When I call it with:

```
declare 
result musicians%rowtype;
begin
result := get_musician_fun(53); 
end;
/
```

I get : `"anonymous block completed"`

But when calling it from PHP:

```
$con = oci_connect("yoni", "yoni", "//localhost/xe");
$s = oci_parse($con, "begin :rc := GET_MUSICIAN_FUN(53); end;");
$rc = oci_new_cursor($con);
oci_bind_by_name($s, ":rc", $rc, -1, OCI_B_CURSOR);
oci_execute($s); // line 41
oci_execute($rc, OCI_DEFAULT);
oci_fetch_all($rc, $res, null, -1, OCI_FETCHSTATEMENT_BY_ROW); // line 43
return $res;
```

I get:

```
Warning
:  oci_execute(): ORA-06550: line 1, column 14:
PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored in... on line 41 

Warning
:  oci_fetch_all(): ORA-24338: statement handle not executed in... on line 43
```

Comment: from SQL developer. I also called that function from a PHP script, gave the same error.

Comment: In SQL developer I use Ctrl-F10 (Run). How can i see the underlying code?

Comment: @YoniLevy:I dont know `PHP` ,but looking to you error statement ,i think you are not fetching it correct in PHP side ,i think you need to declare a variable of your table musician in php and iterate over it .please find the link hope it helps.[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14055397/recover-a-table-of-varchar2-from-a-pl-sql-function-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm no php expert but your trying to fetch an oracle row object into php.
rowtype are used only inside oracle pl/sql code.

try this approach

```
create or replace function get_musician_fun( i_mus_id in musicians.id%type)
return varchar2
as
    musician_row varchar2(32000);
begin
  select m.id||','|| m.first_name||','|| m.last_name||','|| m.born||','|| m.died ||','|| m.picture_path||','|| m.bio
  into o_mus_rec
  from musicians m
  where id = i_mus_id;
  return musician_row;
exception
  when no_data_found then
    raise_application_error(-20005,'found nothing.');
  when too_many_rows then
    raise_application_error(-20006,'found too many.');
  when others then
    raise_application_error(-20007,'cannot get musician.');
end get_musician_fun;
```

and split the result on your php like a csv.

- look at the revised `raise_application_error` bit the code above.
- you might be better of querying the database and fetching the row
  without    a stored procedure.

Comment: I also found out that rowtype can't be used outside oracle, so I decided to do it with a cursor. Anyway your answer will work so I'll accept it. Thanks